# Objectがロックされる原因について

Tags: javascript, web-sql

お世話になっております。

値が読み込めるが、書き込めないと言う現象に遭遇しました。コード中の何処で発生しているか分からないため、どうしたら発生するのかが分かれば探せないかと考えております。

私が把握している限り

```
Object.freeze();
Object.seal();
Object.preventExtensions();
```

などでロックがかかっているのでは？と疑い `Object.isExtensible();` でチェックをかけたのですが`true`が返り変更可能と判断されます。

jQueryを使っているので`$.extend(true, {}, object);`で無理やりディープコピーして対処しているのですが、事故の元なので根本から解決したいと考えております。

また、このObjectの大本のデータは`Web SQL Database`から取得しております。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

コードがないので推測ですが、取得したデータを直接変更されているのではないでしょうか？
本家の方で、websql の resultset は、readonly であると、回答がありました。

> According to the Web SQL Spec SQLResultSetRowList in SQLResultSet
>   Interface is readonly.

[javascript - WebSQL: Are returned rows in SQLResultSetRowList immutable? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999906/websql-are-returned-rows-in-sqlresultsetrowlist-immutable)

Answer (score 0):

解決したコードも添付しておきます。
なんとなく、察しておりましたがやはり読み込み専用なのですね……
参照渡しで配列を組んでいたので、そこを変更して複製するように致しました。

```
var result_record = null;
function find_success(tx, results) {
    var find_row = results.rows.length;
    result_record = new Array();
    for (var n = 0; n < find_row; n++) {
        result_record[n] = $.extend(true, {}, results.rows.item(n));
    }
    callback_all();
}
```